# Media query isn't displaying correctly on Shopify

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries, shopify

I wanted to change how my site displays my products on a mobile device.
As standard it was displaying one item per row and i wanted to show two items per row.

I used the following CSS to acheive this:

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
.product-item{
  width: 50%;
}
}
```

I tested in chrome and firefox browser tools and it appeared to work fine on mobile view.

On a real phone there is white gaps and sometimes only 1 item per line.

Can anyone help? My website url is: DELETED URL

Update: Screenshot of what happens DELETED URL

Comment: on which device you were testing

Comment: iPhone 6 using safari and firefox. iPhone X using safari

Comment: your issue is only on iPhone 6 I tested with other devices and its working fine

Comment: Ok thanks, i will target that device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a temporary fix. I used:

```css
@media only screen and (max-width:600px) {
  .product-item{
    float : left !important;
    width: 50% !important;
    border: red solid;
    box-sizing:border-box  
  }
 }
```

I could see the first item was messing up the layout. I removed it from the category and re added it at the bottom. This is by no means a fix but it is a good solution to fix the display while i fix the parse errors.

This wouldn't have been possible without the help from @Thorsten Wolske and @Nikhil Gangurde

Answer (score 0):

Your code is missing this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
```

- Without the viewport some mobile browsers wont display your page correct.
- Take care that all classes or ids you want to be reponsive are corret declared
  for each device.
- add media queries for devices you want to support,
  this list from css-tricks.com could be helpful:
  https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

if you want to align everything in a correct row the classes eventually need a float declaration:

```
@media only screen and (max-width:600px) {
.product-item{
 float : left;
 width: 50%;
 }
 }
```

If you get spacings that should not be there, there is very simple solution:

```
 *{
  margin : 0 ;
  padding : 0 ;
 }
```

Your css also suffers some parse errors which could also lead to some 
errors. 
Here is a unicorn test of your shop:
https://validator.w3.org/unicorn/check?ucn_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fblupstore.com%2F&ucn_task=conformance#

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I added the meta, changed the media query and tried with and without the margin/padding. The issue still remains :( Does that mean it will never work until the parse errors are fixed?

Comment: To avoid display errors it is the best way to fix parse errors. You also could check the whole css for classes that are declared multiple times for the same reolution, this could lead to errors too.

Answer (score 0):

You can add some css style.

```
@media only screen and (max-width:600px) {
 .product-item:nth-child(2n+1) {
   clear: left !important;
 }
}
```